# How to get an adaptive landscape from a fitness function?

Tags: evolution, natural-selection, fitness

In [Schluter (2000)](https://www.google.ca/books/edition/The_Ecology_of_Adaptive_Radiation/Q1wxNmLAL10C?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=The%20ecology%20of%20adaptive%20radiation&printsec=frontcover), it is mentioned that one can convert a fitness function (see image (a)) to an adaptive landscape (see (b) and (c)). The key is to calculate the mean phenotype of a population and calculate the mean fitness value for that population (based on the fitness of each individuals). The shaded area in (a) under the 2 peaks curve is a population distribution of phenotype z. But like the image shows, how can one draw the adaptive landscape if you have only one population?

I get that the fitness landscape can be calculated with splines and the results plotted as the predicted values of the spline analysis. But how can one generate an adaptive landscape? In the lab, it would be to generate new populations with the whole range of phenotypes and get the mean fitness of the population. But for organisms that sampled in the wild, it is not possible to get the full range of phenotypes and thus calculate different mean fitness across the whole range of phenotypes. How to get a adaptive landscape with phenotypes (and possibly from populations found in the wild?).

[image]